# Count and remove duplicates in keys while preserving values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have collated some data and made them into a dictionary as follows:

```
gen_dict = {
 "item_C_v001" : "jack",
 "item_C_v002" : "kris",
 "item_A_v003" : "john",
 "item_B_v006" : "peter",
 "item_A_v005" : "john",
 "item_A_v004" : "dave"
}
```

I am trying to print out the results in the following format:

```
Item Name     | No. of Vers.      | User
item_A        | 3                 | dave, john
item_B        | 1                 | peter
item_C        | 2                 | jack, kris
```

where it will tabulates similar versions into 1 line, while counting how many versions there are and at the same time, stating the user names..

I am having trouble of integrating in the user names. I used the `set()` command, and that seems to apply for all my 3 rows of output.
Even so, while my 'Item Name' and 'no. of Vers.' column does seems correct, are there any ways in which I can check if the number of versions it found does adhere to the name? It is possible for me to count it manually if I have a small data but what if I got big data?

```
strip_ver_list = []
user_list = []
for item_name, user in gen_dict.iteritems():
    # Strip out the version digits
    strip_ver = item_name[:-3]
    strip_ver_list.append(strip_ver)
    user_list.append(user)


# This will count and remove the duplicates
versions_num = dict((duplicate, strip_ver_list.count(duplicate)) for duplicate in strip_ver_list)

for name, num in sorted(versions_num.iteritems()):
    print "Version Name : {0}\nNo. of Versions : {1}\nUsers : {2}".format(name, num, set(user_list))
```

This is the ouput I have gotten:

```
Item Name     | No. of Vers.      | User
item_A        | 3                 | set(['dave', 'john', 'jack', 'kris', 'peter'])
item_B        | 1                 | set(['dave', 'john', 'jack', 'kris', 'peter'])
item_C        | 2                 | set(['dave', 'john', 'jack', 'kris', 'peter'])
```

This is the only method I can think up of.. But if there are any other viable methods to get around this, please do share with me

Comment: What is `duplicate`?

Comment: Edited, I have omitted out a portion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `defaultdict` to aggregate the data. Roughly:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> gen_dict = {
...  "item_C_v001" : "jack",
...  "item_C_v002" : "kris",
...  "item_A_v003" : "john",
...  "item_B_v006" : "peter",
...  "item_A_v005" : "john",
...  "item_A_v004" : "dave"
... }
```

Now ...

```
>>> versions_num = defaultdict(lambda:dict(versions=set(), users = set()))
>>> for item_name, user in gen_dict.items():
...     strip_ver = item_name[:-5]
...     version_num = item_name[-3:]
...     versions_num[strip_ver]['versions'].add(version_num)
...     versions_num[strip_ver]['users'].add(user)
...
```

Finally,

```
>>> for item, data in versions_num.items():
...     print("Item {} \tno. of Versions: {}\tUsers:{}".format(item, len(data['versions']), ",".join(data['users'])))
...
Item item_B     no. of Versions: 1      Users:peter
Item item_A     no. of Versions: 3      Users:john,dave
Item item_C     no. of Versions: 2      Users:kris,jack
>>>
```

And if you want it sorted:

```
>>> for item, data in sorted(versions_num.items()):
...     print("Item {} \tno. of Versions: {}\tUsers:{}".format(item, len(data['versions']), ",".join(data['users'])))
...
Item item_A     no. of Versions: 3      Users:john,dave
Item item_B     no. of Versions: 1      Users:peter
Item item_C     no. of Versions: 2      Users:kris,jack
```

Comment: I suppose using of `defaultdict` means there is no need for me to create new dicts and allows me to keep 'reusing' it?

Comment: @dissidia I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but that sounds reasonable... This structure is already pushing what I would consider clunky and it might be worth making this all a class and encapsualting this logic there.

Comment: I am doing something similar but I am trying to count the number of versions that each user 'occupy' to per key? Using this thread's example, `item_C_v` has 2 overall items, but to list the output for the user column as `jack (1), kris (1)`, is this possible?
I tried using `[(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(gen_dict.values()))]` but this will list out the overall number of versions that each user have without taking per key into account..

Comment: @yan I'm afraid I am unable to help you much on this. Perhaps the others can help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the lists by the item name and extract the users from each group, otherwise the *user_list* will always be a global list of *users*:

```
from itertools import groupby
# split the item_version
sorted_ver_num = sorted(k.rsplit("_", 1) + [v] for k, v in gen_dict.items())

# group the results by the item name
for k, g in groupby(sorted_ver_num, key = lambda x: x[0]):
    # extract the user list within each group
    # user_list = [user for *_, user in g]  
    user_list = [user for _, _, user in g]
    print("Version Name : {0}\nNo. of Versions : {1}\nUsers : {2}".format(k, len(user_list), set(user_list)))


Version Name : item_A
No. of Versions : 3
Users : {'dave', 'john'}
Version Name : item_B
No. of Versions : 1
Users : {'peter'}
Version Name : item_C
No. of Versions : 2
Users : {'kris', 'jack'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to keep track of the users, and an ordinary dict to keep track of the count. The `dict.get()` method allows you to return a default value if the key is not found, in this case `0`, and you just add `1` to it each time the key is found.

```
from collections import defaultdict

gen_dict = {
 "item_C_v001" : "jack",
 "item_C_v002" : "kris",
 "item_A_v003" : "john",
 "item_B_v006" : "peter",
 "item_A_v005" : "john",
 "item_A_v004" : "dave"
}

user_dict = defaultdict(set)
count_dict = {}

for item_name, user in gen_dict.iteritems():
    user_dict[item_name[:-3]].add(user) # Sure you want -3 not -5?
    count_dict[item_name[:-3]] = count_dict.get(item_name[:-3], 0) + 1

for name, num in sorted(count_dict.iteritems()):
    print "Version Name : {0}\nNo. of Versions : {1}\nUsers : {2}".format(
                   name, num, ', '.join(item for item in user_dict[name]))
```

Comment: I did not know that  an integer value can be within `get` command and use it as a 'counter' method to count it!

Comment: @dissidia the `get()` method will return `None` if the key isn't found rather than `KeyError` from `dict[<key_that_doesn't_exist>]`. But if you don't want `None`, as in this case, you can set a default value. In this case, you want to start a counter from `0`. I've found it to be faster than [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Example in IPython:

```
In [1]: gen_dict = {
   ...:  "item_C_v001" : "jack",
   ...:  "item_C_v002" : "kris",
   ...:  "item_A_v003" : "john",
   ...:  "item_B_v006" : "peter",
   ...:  "item_A_v005" : "john",
   ...:  "item_A_v004" : "dave"
   ...: }
```

Get the keys, we'll be needing them more then once.

```
In [2]: keys = tuple(gen_dict.keys())
```

Find the set of items.

```
In [3]: items = set(j[:-5] for j in keys)
```

Table header and template.

```
In [4]: header = 'Item Name     | No. of Vers.      | User'

In [5]: template = '{:14}|{:<15}|{}'
```

Print relevant information for all items.

```
In [6]: print(header)
Item Name     | No. of Vers.      | User

In [7]: for i in items:
   ...:     relevant = tuple(j for j in keys if j.startswith(i))
   ...:     users = set(gen_dict[x] for x in relevant)
   ...:     print(template.format(i, len(relevant), ' '.join(users)))
   ...:     
item_A        |3              |john dave
item_B        |1              |peter
item_C        |2              |kris jack
```